# The webjar for Materialize (v1.0.0-rc.2) can't be downloaded

Tags: java, maven, webjars

A webjar for Materialize in 1.0.0.rc-2 has been recently added (Jul 03, 2018) on org.webjars.bower but it seems it can't be downloaded.

In Eclipse or Intellij maven can't find the artifact.

**`Missing artifact org.webjars.bower:materialize:jar:1.0.0-rc.2`**

As the artifact seems to be available on this url : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2, and on https://www.webjars.org/, why it can't be downloaded?

Extract from the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
    <artifactId>materialize</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-rc.2</version>
</dependency>
```

PS: I am pretty sure it's not a configuration problem on maven, as I don't have any problems with others webjars (for example with jquery).

EDIT: it was a wrong network configuration (proxy, password)

Comment: The files are correctly in Maven Central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/bower/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/ So I'm not sure why they can't be downloaded for you.  Maybe a network issue?

Comment: Yup, it was a network issue. I was pretty sure I checked it many times but It seems no! My bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a network issue : the password was recently changed but not in the proxy configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your missing artifact message, you have the version and packaging reversed. The following downloads successfully:

```
org.webjars.bower:materialize:1.0.0-rc.2:jar
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so, I edited my message with the dependancy